# filter the data from an input string

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

If user inputs the employees details as string and we want the output to display the employees with the top three years of experience in the same order of employee details as they apper in the input string.
For example input string:

```
"EMP101:Jack:CA:jack@yahoo.com:10#EMP102:Jill:Doctor:jill@gmail.com:5#EMP103:Russell:Engineer:r234@yahoo.com:25#EMP104:Monica:Teacher:monica@yahoo.com:4#EMP105:John:Mangaer:john@yahoo.com:8"
```

Output string:
For example input string:

```
"Jack:CA:10#Russell:Engineer:25#John:Mangaer:8"
```

could anyone please tell me how to achive this in shellscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
echo "EMP101:Jack:CA:jack@yahoo.com:10#EMP102:Jill:Doctor:jill@gmail.com:5#EMP103:Russell:Engineer:r234@yahoo.com:25#EMP104:Monica:Teacher:monica@yahoo.com:4#EMP105:John:Mangaer:john@yahoo.com:8" \
    | awk -F '#' 'BEGIN {OFS = "\n"} {$1 = $1; print}' \
    | sort -k 5 -n -r -t : \
    | head -n 3 \
    | sort -k 1 -t : \
    | awk -F : 'BEGIN {OFS = ":"} {print $2, $3, $5}' \
    | paste -d '#' -s
```

Result:

```
Jack:CA:10#Russell:Engineer:25#John:Mangaer:8
```

Sorted again by the first field.

Comment: When you use `#` as field separator, you cannot directly access the colon - delimited fields. And OP wants to limit output fields as far as I understand it

Comment: The output is sorted..it should not be sorted it should be in the same order as the user has inserted it

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `awk`, `sort`, `head` and `paste`:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; OFS=FS=":"} {gsub(/"\n$/,"",$5); print NR,$2,$3,$5}' file  \
  | sort -t':' -k4nr \
  | head -n3 \
  | sort -n \
  | cut -d: -f2-\
  | paste -sd'#'
```

Output:

```
Jack:CA:10#Russell:Engineer:25#John:Mangaer:8
```

- `RS` is "Record Separator", defaults to newline, but your records are separated by `#`
- `FS` is "Field Separator", which is `:` for your data.
- If we use `#` as `RS`, the last field of your last record will include a double qutoe and newline in the end that we'll strip with `gsub`.
- You can add `| sed 's/.*/"\0"/'` to exactly get your output including the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the Output should not be sorted it should be in the same sequesnce as in the inputstring.

Comment: Added output of `NR` and a second `sort`, along with `cut` off the `NR` again.. You might be better off using a more sophisticated tool ... a `python` script or maybe it's possible with `datamash`...

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) Also thanks for detail explaining of each and every step, it helped me to understand the query...Thanks once again :)